# How to change IPython traceback coloring

Tags: ipython, syntax-highlighting, traceback

Coloring traceback is great for fast visual parsing, but default colors for IPython 2.2.0 running on linux bash shell are too much for me.

(I mean, comments in red? really?)

How can the user modify this coloring?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily change IPython text color typing "ipython profile create" and then messing with the config file in ~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py.

Search color with your favorite text editor, "LightBG" will certainly correspond to you, the colors are less "aggressives".

1. Type "ipython profile create"
2. open "~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py"
3. Uncomment line 158 and set the variable to 'LightBG' (c.TerminalInteractiveShell.colors = 'LightBG')